# @Singleton @Inject-ed in @WebServlet seems to create multiple instances

Tags: jakarta-ee, singleton, ejb, cdi

I've the below `@Singleton` EJBs:

```
@Singleton
public class RunBean {

  private int id = new Random().nextInt();

  public void printID() {
    System.out.println("ID = " + id);
  }

}
```

```
@Singleton
public class ParentBean {

  @Inject
  private RunBean runBean;

  public void start() {
    runBean.printID();
  }

}
```

I'm `@Inject`-ing them in the below web servlet:

```
public class Servlet extends HttpServlet {

  @Inject
  private RunBean runBean;

  @Inject
  private ParentBean parentBean;

  public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
      runBean.printID();  // out: ID = 69743
      parentBean.start(); // out: ID = 193
  }

}
```

I expected to see the same ID being printed. Why are they different?

Comment: Is that `@javax.ejb.Singleton`?

Comment: Yes what annotation class is that.

Comment: I suspect you might be a victim of a CDI quirk: either use only `@EJB` to inject your singletons everywhere (instead of `@Inject`) or add `@ApplicationScoped` to your `@Singleton`s and keep using `@Inject`

Comment: Yes thank. RunBean is `javax.inject.Singleton`. But ParentBean is `com.google.inject.Singleton` (this implementation need for use library). So I can not inject CDI Singleton in `com.google.inject.Singleton`? But I need him there. What should I do to get bean? Use `new initialcontext().lookup`?

Comment: Do you deploy your application on a Java EE container? Or do you use 3rd party lib for injecting (e.g.:guice)?

Comment: Java EE. I use for deploy Jboss EAP 6.4  Guice use only for work with  gwtrpcplus [http://code.google.com/p/gwtrpcplus/]

Comment: Google's implementation of `@Singleton` is just weird

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. Really strange behavior.

Answer (score 1):

You should only `@Inject` EJBs (such as your `@Singleton` beans) on a JavaEE 7 or newer server.

In a Java EE6 environment you must use `@EJB`.